# Should we do something about enormous numbers of edits in short times?

Tags: discussion, edits

First of all, dear [Antonio Carlos Ribeiro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1959747/antonio-carlos-ribeiro), please don't take it as a personal...

Today, I just looked up the [editor parts on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors) and I saw this user made 543 edits in 24 hours. When I look at [his revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1959747/antonio-carlos-ribeiro?tab=activity&sort=revisions), his edits only include (I look at all revisions on last 27 pages) this:

- add [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) tag which questions have already [laravel-4](/questions/tagged/laravel-4) tag.

Looks like all the edits he made are like this. Since his reputation is over 3k, the system does allow this kind of minor editing without any approval. (As we all know, under 2k reputation users need 3 approval for editing).

Does our system need to prevent this number of minor edits?

Or it is okay for everybody since the user has over 3k reputation?

Comment: Possibly he wants to *earn* those `laravel-*` badges real fast!

Comment: Also, is adding a general tag ('laravel') to a question that already has a specific tag ('laravel-4') of any use?

Comment: @CodeCaster Me neither.. Seems pointless to me adding `laravel` tag which already has `laravel-4` tag.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to add the generic tag to a version specific tag, *but* that should be discussed before hand (either here or in the chat). Personally, I consider every mass-retagging effort which was not discussed beforehand as...uhm...unnecessary.

Comment: @CodeCaster it can be, for example if someone tags a question SQL-Server-2012 and they get an answer, then someone later is using SQL-Server-2014 and have the same question, they should be able to find the question under SQL-Server. Now I don't go out of my way to re-tag questions like that, but when I do come across them naturally, I sometimes will make the effort.

Comment: @KateGregory I don't really see it as a duplicate as the difference between gaining reputation for edits and not doing so is pretty significant.

Comment: He thinks it's correct, but it should be preceded by Meta discussion.

Comment: Personally I think questions should only have a version-specific tag **if the question is actually version-specific**, rather than containing code that works in any version. It can also be a "from this version onwards" kind of thing, but 10 years from now, all versions will probably apply, so the tag will no longer be applicable, thus only if the issue is **unique** to some version, but maybe there is some sense in keeping it around for a while. ... and probably always include the generic language tag. All in all, the tag system doesn't cater for versions well. Well, that's my opinion anyway.

Comment: [This user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1926343/devo?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) has done the same thing but he has the rep<2k the edits may be for reputations, nothing personal.